# How can I do an autocorrelation on a Radon Transofrm?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have the following code

```
I = imread('img.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I);
theta = 1:180;
[R,xp] = radon(I,theta);
```

how can I apply auto-correlation on this radon transformation of an image?

I have the following mathematical formula which describes the process I need:

[image: where g(s,0) is the radon transformation]
where g(s,0) is the radon transformation

which function is the equivalent in Matlab?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matlab function for taking auto correlation: `xcorr(R)`

Comment: I've edited my question, will xcorr cover my formula I've posted?

Comment: Please try it and let me know.